# Frontend performance issue

Tags: php, mysql, performance, azure, frontend

My website is running under `LAMP` environment on windows azure. Website is taking too much time to load. And sometimes it just opens very quickly. I tried to debug it from `slow_query_log` in `mysql`. Everything looks ok there as it's intermittent issue. I am 99% sure that it's not server side issue.

I also tried with frontend monitoring by below script:

```
// When the DOM is loaded
$(function(){
    console.log('Start ' + new Date().getTime());
});
// When all the images are loaded
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log('End ' + new Date().getTime());
});
```

Result:

```
Start 1443799367774
End 1443799368096
```

I couldn't figure it out what's wrong here. Please advice me how can I debug more deeply or is there any solution to overcome this problem. Thanks.

Comment: use http://www.webpagetest.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether any configurations or applications are set or installed on The **temporary disk** which is automatically created for you, and the disk is typically `/dev/sdb` and is formatted and mounted to `/mnt/` resource by the Azure Linux Agent. If your site cache is stored on the temporary disk, it will occur your issue because of the intermittent lifetime of temporary disk.

We can get more information about temporary disk at [Understanding the temporary drive on Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2013/12/07/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines.aspx) and [Optimizing MySQL Performance on Azure Linux VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-optimize-mysql-perf/).

Furthermore, we can check the bottleneck of the application at the monitor tab of the azure manage portal. There are CPU Percentage, disk i/o and network metrics shown in timeline.

By the way, for website performance, I suggest you can try @Anthony’s suggestion and find the large elapsed time of files for further optimization.

If you have any concern, please feel free to let me know.